# Navigating between social media in react

Tags: reactjs

I imported social media logos to my react code, now I want to pass a link to it so that the logo will be responsive.

I have tried using react-dom, but I'm getting it confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to make the displayed logos into hyperlinks that take you to the social media pages, you can wrap it in an  tag with the 'href' property set to whatever URL you want to make it clickable.

Example:

```
<a href="https://google.com">
  <img src="path-to-icon" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used the HTML format, I wrapped the whole logo tag with the  tag and assigned the link using herf.

Here is the code

```
<a
            href="https://www.instagram.com/fajuks/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
                <Logo1 >
               < FaInstagram/>
               </Logo1>
         </a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are really trying to do. If you want it as a link, use `<a><img></a>`.By responsive, do you mean how it would look like in different devices? If so, you might have to include `@media screen` in your css.